# Trying to use npm to install node modules trhu a script gives a EINVALIDTAGNAME error, Writing them on shell works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js

`npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME`
`": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`

I tried creating a script to install some Node modules on ubuntu 18.04, The commands where simple:
npm install module
npm install module2
npm install module3 and so on

The commands work fine when i run them on console but if i run them in a .sh script they give this error:

`npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME`
`": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`

Comment: Can you give the exact script you are trying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.